# Why the features are overwritten when extracted using pycaffe?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I observed that the features are overwritten when I extract them using  **pycaffe**. My code is as follows:

```
tImg_1 = misc.imread('1.jpg')
tImg_1 = tImg_1[:,:,::-1] # color channel swap
tImg_2 = misc.imread('2.jpg')
tImg_2 = tImg_2[:,:,::-1] # color channel swap

tImg_1 = (np.float32(tImg_1)- 127.5)/128 # mean substruction
tImg_2 = (np.float32(tImg_2)- 127.5)/128 # mean substruction

tI_1 = np.moveaxis(tImg_1, 0, 1) # Transpose
tI_2 = np.moveaxis(tImg_2, 0, 1) # Transpose

# Extract features
tI_1 = np.reshape(tImg_1, (1, tImg_1.shape[2], tImg_1.shape[0], tImg_1.shape[1]))
tI_2 = np.reshape(tImg_2, (1, tImg_2.shape[2], tImg_2.shape[0],     tImg_2.shape[1]))                

net.blobs['data'].data[...] = tI_1
net.forward() 
fts_1 = net.blobs['fc5'].data
print(fts_1[0, 0])                 

net.blobs['data'].data[...] = tI_2
net.forward() 
fts_2 = net.blobs['fc5'].data                  

print(fts_2[0, 0])                 
print(fts_1[0, 0])
```

Executing this provides the following output:

```
0.508398
-0.176945
-0.176945
```

That means the values of **fts_1** is overwritten by **fts_2**. How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fts_1` is just pointing to `net.blobs['fc5'].data`. You need to make a deepcopy of the object. So your first assignment should be `fts_1 = copy.deepcopy(net.blobs['fc5'].data)`

Comment: Thank you. Then this is a python specific problem. Nothing to do with caffe!